# How to write a catch-all Windows hook recipient function?

Tags: c, hook, setwindowshookex

I want to create a generic, catch-all Windows API (and application function) hook recipient to permit dynamic and safe hooking.

The idea is to:

- create and set a hook on the target function which is determined by user at runtime,
- then, once it is intercepted, pass the values to a Lua runtime so the user can safely and dynamically inspect the values, or edit
- pass control to the original function.

Decoding the function arguments to meaningful values can be left to the Lua script once it has them.

Any hints, tips welcome.

P.S. I am thinking of using mhook2.3

Comment: Can't you just set a shell hook? After the hooking code is in, you subclass the main window of the target process with your own window proc that exports the arguments to the LUA script.

Comment: Most of the stuff I want to hook into doesn't have a window :(

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces is this useful? Also Windows via C/C++ the book. But you need an entry point into the target application - like knowing where the functions you want to hook are; you create a thread, and in that thread you insert your code into those functions; here's my take on the matter - http://elf.cs.pub.ro/so/wiki/laboratoare/resurse/injections